# How to authenticate user session from another server?

Tags: node.js, security, http, authentication, socket.io

This is the use-case:

1. server A authenticate the user and creates a session for the user.
2. The user wants to communicate with server B.
3. server B needs to authenticate the user before the user can proceed.

My Question:
How should server B authenticate the user?

Note:
server A is a node.js, express
server B is socket.io dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of the many non-in-memory session stores. Some example session store Express/Connect middleware  include:

- [Cookie store](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session)
- [Redis store](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis)
- [MongoDB store](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)
- [CouchDB store](https://github.com/tdebarochez/connect-couchdb)
- [Riak store](https://github.com/frank06/connect-riak)
- [memcached store](https://github.com/balor/connect-memcached)
- [leveldb store](https://github.com/wolfeidau/connect-leveldb)
- [MySQL store](https://github.com/nlf/connect-mysql)
- [PostgreSQL store](https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple)
- [Firebase store](https://github.com/ca98am79/connect-firebase)

If you are creating a SPA (e.g. with angular.js), you could also use tokens (e.g. [JWT](http://jwt.io/)) instead of using cookies to track sessions.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Can you explain further about "session stores" and how practically, server B authenticate the user? (is it relying on the user's IP?)

Comment: Usually it relies on a session cookie in the user's browser. However there are other methods if you have a SPA (e.g. angular.js), such as using tokens (e.g. [JWT](http://jwt.io/)) or something similar.